# Analyze changes of voice volume (dB) throughout the day

Tags: windows, monitoring, speech-recognition

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can record and analyze changes of voice volume (dB) throughout the day when I speak to the computer's microphone.

Any price, license is fine.

Use case: I use speech recognition throughout the day, and one of the guideline for vocal hygiene is to change how loud I speak, so I want to ensure my pitch variation is appropriate.

Comment: *Deadline*?  Do you mean goals/targets?

Comment: Do you use a headset microphone?  I'm thinking you could try moving the microphone closer or farther from your mouth during the course of the day, or moving a desk microphone forward or back on the desk.  Also, perhaps you can change the threshold on the microphone at different times of day.  My experience with voice recognition software is that when the person dictating doesn't speak loudly enough, the software immediately shows its confusion.

Comment: @aparente001 I use a headset microphone. Good idea regarding the changing the microphone volume. Changing the position of the microphone wouldn't be good with my headset.

Comment: I see.  Have you thought about experimenting with a desk microphone?  I have seen one used extremely effectively.  Here's an analogy.  I have a back injury.  It is helpful for me to switch chairs every couple of hours.  I wonder whether switching microphones from time to time would similarly be helpful for you.  Partly because of the distance idea, and partly because switching equipment can be refreshing. // Please do post an update after you try the idea of changing the microphone volume.

Comment: @aparente001 Interesting suggestion. One issue with a desk microphone is that it does not follow your mouth when you turn the head, which I often have to do as I use several monitors. And I would prefer not to use a omnidirectional microphone, to avoid surrounding noise. But I have also seen some people using desk microphones. Actually I used to use one but the headset microphone I purchased later seems to yield more accurate speech recognition.

Comment: The person I saw using a desk microphone has Tourette Syndrome.  He did not remain immobile while dictating.  Do you want me to try to find out what model or type of microphone he uses?